# Stop Minecraft server in Docker when container stops

Tags: docker, minecraft

I'm building a Minecraft server in Docker. Whenever the docker stops, the Minecraft Java process doesn't stop properly, even though I run it in PID 1 and execute the entrypoint as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'stop\n' TERM

while true; do
    java -jar Minecraft.jar
done
```

Is my entrypoint correct?

Answer (score 0):

try to run it using a trap https://serverfault.com/a/518182/281162 this should help you passing on the right SIGNALS and properly wait for the java-process to shutdown.

Eventhough this example is for tomcat, you can simple replace catalina.run with java -jar ..